# Schedule Process at random time in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

I have a queue of data which has a field "created time". I will insert items in the queue in ascending created time order. Now I have to run a process at a created time of every first entry in the queue and it should run only one time .

Ex --

There are five entry in the queue's with time 
1) 1:00 
2) 1:15 
3) 1:20 
4) 1:30 
5) 2:00

So my scheduled process should run at 1:00 pm then at 1:15pm then at 1:20pm then at 1:20 and at last at 2:00pm only and not recur after certain time.

I am using spring boot. Is there any way to do this in spring.

Comment: you can use a cron trigger and define all those times:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-trigger-implementations

Comment: You can use `@Scheduled` annotation or there is a good combination using `Spring-boot` and `Quartz`. But I have to flag your question as off topic because there is no code were we can help you.

Comment: But this is a queue and an entry can be made at any time in the queue.So I myself cannot decide what time the job will run

Comment: Although not a Spring solution, consider using Java's [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` can be introduced as a bean and injected where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure TaskScheduler using as implementation ThreadPoolTaskScheduler for example, which basically is a wrapper around ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor:

```
@Bean
public TaskScheduler taskScheduler ()
{
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.initialize();
    return taskScheduler;
}
```

Then you can process your queue in a sumular fashion using the scheduler:

```
public class MyQueueParser
{
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    public void parseQueue()
    {
        for (Item item: myQueue)
        {
            scheduler.schedule(() -> {
                // do the work
            }, item.getCreationTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Scheduler takes runnable to execute and a time at which to run the tast. TaskScheduler also allows you to use triggers. Check the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html)